# Подскажите как функция делает из шаблонной массив?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Здравствуйте подскажите как вот эта функция делает из шаблонной строки массив не могу понять

```js
const name = 'Bill';
console.log(upperName`Hello ${name}`);

function upperName(literals, value) {
  console.log(literals, value);
};
```

Comment: это встроенная способность.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это называется [template-literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings#%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B)

> Первый аргумент такой функции содержит массив строковых значений, а остальные содержат выражения из подстановок.